# Cloudflare and local website displaying mailchimp differently?

Tags: html, css, cloudflare, mailchimp

I expect to see this when running my cloudflare deployment:
[correct dep.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5LDm.png)
Instead I see this:
[incorrect dep.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZwcQ.png)

Not sure where to start with this one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in the Cloudflare Dashboard that minimizes HTML, JS, and CSS files, which could lead to certain issues. Please attempt to disable this option to see if it resolves the problem.

Reference: https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/speed/optimization-file-size/using-cloudflare-auto-minify/